# Get index of an Item from an other List

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I started to use providers but I have a problem. I want to get the index of items that are in an other list in an other screen. How can i get them ? I have two screens: a home screen and a favorite screen and I have a `listView` in each. I want to get the index of the item in the home screen when it is remove from the favorite screen. This is the link of my code on GitHub : https://github.com/Rianou20/my_app_from_scratch/tree/master/my_app_from_scratch. And some relevant parts of my code :

**favModel.dart**

```
class FavModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Item> favList = [];
  List<bool> isInFav = [];
  

  addInFavorite(title, description, index){
    Item item = Item(title: title, description: description, );
    favList.add(item);
    isInFav[index] = true;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  removeOfFavorite(int index, int index2){
    favList.removeAt(index);
    isInFav[index2] = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  implement(){
    isInFav.add(false);
  }
}
```

**favorite_screen.dart**

```
class Favorite extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Favorite'),
      ),
      body: Consumer<FavModel>(
        builder: (context, favModel, child) {
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: favModel.favList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return TextObject(favModel.favList[index].title,
                                    favModel.favList[index].description),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                                  child: GestureDetector(
                                      child: Icon(
                                        Icons.favorite,
                                        color: Colors.red,
                                        size: 32,
                                      ),
                                      onTap: () {
                                        favModel.removeOfFavorite(index, index);
                                      }),
                                ),
           });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**home_screen.dart**

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                fullscreenDialog: true,
                builder: (context) {
                  return Favorite();
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Consumer<FavModel>(builder: (context, favModel, child) {
        return ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: false,
            itemCount: itemData.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              favModel.implement();
              return TextObject(
                 itemData[index].title, itemData[index].description),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                          child: GestureDetector(
                              child: Icon(
                                favModel.isInFav.elementAt(index)
                                    ? Icons.favorite
                                    : Icons.favorite_border,
                                color:
                                    favModel.isInFav[index] ? Colors.red : null,
                                size: 32,
                              ),
                              onTap: () {
                                favModel.isInFav[index]
                                    ? null
                                    : Provider.of<FavModel>(context,
                                            listen: false)
                                        .addInFavorite(
                                        itemData[index].title,
                                        itemData[index].description,
                                        index,
                                      );
                              }),
              );
            });
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Where I want to get the index is in the favorite_screen.dart at this line `favModel.removeOfFavorite(index, index);`

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact use case, you can potentially store the removed values in a list and use them on your home screen.

```
class FavModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Item> favList = [];
  List<bool> isInFav = [];
  List<int> _removedItemIndexList = []
  
  get removedItemIndexList => _removedItemIndexList; 
  
  addInFavorite(title, description, countdown, imageURL, index){
    Item item = Item(title: title, description: description, countdown:countdown, imageURL: imageURL);
    favList.add(item);
    isInFav[index] = true;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  removeOfFavorite(int index, int index2){
    favList.removeAt(index);
    isInFav[index2] = false;
    _addToRemovedIndexList(index); 
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void _addToRemovedIndexList(int index) {
    _removedItemIndexList.add(index);
  }

  implement(){
    isInFav.add(false);
  }
}
```

And then use on **home_sreen.dart** as

```
...
body: Consumer<FavModel>(builder: (context, favModel, child) {
            List<int> removedIndexes = favModel.removedItemIndexList;
            return ListView.builder( ... ) };
```

Note that the FavModel provider class must be lifted above then home_screen.dart on the widget tree in order to be able to access its values. i.e. you would want to do something like this in your **main.dart**

```
...
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
            value: FavModel(),
          ),
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(...
```

Comment: It's probably not going to work out the way I want it to. In fact, I have a first list that doesn't change content, it's just buttons that change. I want that when an item is removed from the favorites list that on the menu list the button changes to the item that was removed on the second list. Maybe I need to create an id for each item but I don't really know how to do it and how to use it.

Comment: I need the place of the item in the first screen that corresponds to the item that is removed from the second.